# How can i fix POST 404 error using go? It's not source code error

Tags: go

I enter my source code with golang book. 
My source code is same with my golang book's source code

check the source code

-------golang--------

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
   r := &router{make(map[string]map[string]HandlerFunc)}

   r.HandleFunc("GET", "/", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintln(c.ResponseWriter, "welcome!")
   })

   r.HandleFunc("GET", "/about", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintln(c.ResponseWriter, "about")
   })

   r.HandleFunc("GET", "/users/:id", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, "retrieve user %v\n",
       c.Params["id"])
   })

   r.HandleFunc("GET", "/users/:user_id/addresses/:address_id", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, "retrieve user %v's address %v\n",
       c.Params["user_id"], c.Params["address_id"])
   })

   r.HandleFunc("POST", "/users", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, "create user\n")
   })

   r.HandleFunc("POST", "/users/:user_id/addresses", func(c *Context) {
       fmt.Fprintf(c.ResponseWriter, "create user %v's address\n", c.Params["user_id"])
   })

   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

PS C:\Users\user\go> curl http://localhost:8080/users/1
curl : 404 page not found
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://localhost:8080/users/1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: What is `router`?

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please reformat your question to make it readable.

Answer (score -1):

when you define your uri for HandlerFunc, parameters must go between {}

/users/{id} instead of /users/:id